# What do the red dots next to the question mean in SO Teams?

Tags: support, notifications, stack-overflow-for-teams

There is a red dot in the front of this question, what exactly does this mean:

[image]

Comment: ... And why isn't it free-hand?

Comment: When you right-click and inspect this element, is there some class name that reveals the meaning?

Comment: class shows the following `bg-red-500 bar-circle d-inline-block activity-indicator mr4`

Comment: Maybe the answer was edited?

Comment: @Cerbrus - I asked and answered my own and never updated that either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When there are new questions in your team since you last visited then there is a red dot next to your team in the left nav. If you click on your team that red dot should be dismissed and a red dot will show up next to the new items in the question list. You don't actually have to visit the questions to clear the red dot. It should clear on its own once you've "seen" the new questions in the list.

Why did we add this? We realized that some team members would go to their team less frequently but would land on public SO as a result of their normal troubleshooting efforts. We wanted a way to identify for them when there was new activity in their team. This is very much an MVP version of this feature. Feedback is welcome.

Comment: The strange thing is this thing doesnt go away for me.  Whether I view it or not.

Comment: Well now its gone...so maybe it is working as intended.  Strange for a while I saw it in my list and even after seeing it I still saw the red dot.  But now after I click backed to my team it went away.  Could a tooltip help?

Comment: @JonH I don't think the logic is perfect or caching is effecting it in some way. Not sure which. But it generally solves the problem. Particularly for the occasional visitor to the team.

Comment: Isn't it amazing when applications grow they become so complex that people don't know really how they work or what could be causing certain things.  No issue I can deal with it as now I understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @JonH That's part of it in some cases. In this case, it is more like we are moving fast and haven't really dug into it. That's why I called this an MVP of the feature.

Comment: @JonH Did you perhaps hit the back button (not reload) after viewing it?

Comment: Is there a `title` or `attr` property for this red circle?

Comment: I agree with Lightness on a `title` or `attr`. This would make it more clear to normal users what it is, and it would make the site more accessible to people with disabilities. That said, there is clearly a part missing to this feature, as I had red dots on my team questions even though I had already answered those questions.

Comment: There is a title on the left nav. It says, "New questions have been asked in your team". We need to add one to the red dot on the question.