# What are those red dots in the question list?

Tags: support, questions, user-interface

Currently my experience looks like this:

[image]

Is this the same mechanism used for Teams as in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368523/what-do-the-red-dots-next-to-the-question-mean-in-so-teams)?

Can this be disabled somehow?

Comment: Questions with updates since you last saw the list. Personally I find them quite annoying and not useful, but hey ho.

Comment: If you are using uBlock Origin you can use a custom filter to disable the red dot: `stackoverflow.com##.mr4.activity-indicator.d-inline-block.bar-circle.bg-red-500`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are questions with updates since you last saw the list. Hover over the dot and it says:

> This question has new activity

For example:

[image]

Comment: is this a new feature? I don't have any dots

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's been around for months, it may only show on custom filters, I guess you're not using them?

Comment: I used them before and I have tried right now and I see nothing ...

Comment: Hmmm, weird... I switched to a custom filter today (due to changes in the standard view?) and that was the reason I see them? If this is only for filters it should be customizable IMHO

Comment: @TemaniAfif Wait for new questions then try again perhaps?